# Адаптивний интерфейс WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет, относительно недавно начал изучать WPF, что посоветуете по адаптивному дизайну вроде как его еще називають "жидким"
У меня есть окно которое должно при растяжении на весь экран пропорционально растягивать элементы управления и т.д...
Вот примерный код зарание всем спасибо)

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PRAKTIKA_FULL"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes" x:Class="PRAKTIKA_FULL.Alphabet"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Алфавіт" Height="600" Width="800" Background="{x:Null}">
    <Grid Background="#FF3C3939"
          Height="597"
          VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="285"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="612"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer
 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="188" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="16,0,81,112" Grid.Row="1" >
            <StackPanel
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                  Height="1575"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                  Width="214" Grid.RowSpan="4">
                <Button Content="А" Click="A_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Б" Click="B_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="В" Click="V_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Г" Click="H_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Ґ" Click="H1_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Д" Click="D_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Е" Click="E_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Э" Click="E1_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Ж" Click="G_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="З" Click="Z_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="И" Click="I_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="І" Click="I1_Click" Height="37"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Ї" Click="I2_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Й" Click="J1_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="К" Click="K_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Л" Click="L_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="М" Click="MM_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Н" Click="N_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="О" Click="O_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="П" Click="P_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Р" Click="R_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="С" Click="C_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Т" Click="TTT_Click" Height="37"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="У" Click="Y_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Ф" Click="F_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Х" Click="X_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Ц" Click="TS_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Ч" Click="CH_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Ш" Click="SH_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Щ" Click="SH1_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Ь" Click="J_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Ю" Click="YU_Click" Height="39"/>
                <Separator Opacity="0" Height="5"/>
                <Button Content="Я" Click="YA_Click" Height="39"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <MediaElement 
            x:Name="Media" 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Height="440" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Width="476" Margin="19,30,12,142" Grid.Row="1"/>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Вопрос в чем? Вот код, ок, увидели, должен дать одинаковые кнопки, расположенные в столбик, что надо? Какое поведение ожидается? Если речь про "заполнение", то почему кнопки друг за другом и имеют статичный размер? А это вообще, что за ужас? `Width="476" Margin="19,30,12,142"`. Забудьте про дизайнер студии, пишите код сами!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/10105?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то вы хотите разместить с левой части список алфавита, а все оставшееся место занять плеером, да так, чтоб при изменении размера окна, элементы подстраивались. Если так, то давайте сделаем нечто такое:

Для начала запомните ряд самых главных правил:

1. Не используйте дизайнер студии в качестве инструмента для создания интерфейса, он для этого попросту не пригоден, создавая вам код по типу `Width="476" Margin="19,30,12,142"`, из-за чего все ваши элементы будут скакать.
2. Старайтесь отделять данные от UI, контролы не должны хранить что-либо в себе, их задачи лишь взаимодействовать с пользователем. Научитесь делать привязки, использовать коллекции и др.
3. Если вы хотите "адаптивный интерфейс", то забудьте про указание статичных размеров, не ограничивайте контролы, дайте им свободу, пусть сами выбирают что и как.

Теперь давайте сделаем простую разметку:

```xml
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="120"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
    <!--#region Левая сторона-->
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0 0 1 0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding}" Padding="10" Margin="5" MinWidth="50"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <system:String>А</system:String>
            <system:String>Б</system:String>
            <system:String>В</system:String>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <!--#endregion-->
    
    <!--#region Правая сторона-->
    <MediaElement Grid.Column="1" Stretch="UniformToFill"
        Source="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4"/>
    <!--#endregion-->        
</Grid>
```

Заметьте, тут не используются явные размеры, мы играемся только с пропорциями и позиционированием объектов.

В итоге получаем следующее:

[image: Result]

Как видите, наш интерфейс успешно подстраивается под изменения окна. Осталось избавиться от статичного контента и сделать нужную логику. Давайте покажу самое простое, как избавиться от данных в контолах:

- Удаляем

  ```xml
  <system:String>А</system:String>
  <system:String>Б</system:String>
  <system:String>В</system:String>
  ```
- Дописываем `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"`
- В c# коде окна пишем прям в конструкторе `DataContext = this`.
- Рядом с конструктором пишем `public char[] Items { get; } = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя".ToCharArray();`

Весь код получается такой:

```
public char[] Items { get; } = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя".ToCharArray();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

[image: Items]

Вот вы и научились простой привязке данных, где нужные данные находятся в отдельном списке, а UI лишь отображает их.

Comment: Интересненько, спасибо буду над етим работать =)

Comment: Привет. извини, подскажи как лучше вставить в WPF большое количество тексту ?)

Comment: @KOKO Зависит от задачи. Если просто текст, он не слишком большой и не нужно выделение, то можно использовать `TextBlock`, если нужна возможность выделить мышью, скопировать, может отредактировать, то `TextBox` в помощь, а если нужно еще и форматирование текста (жирный, курсив и др.), то `FlowDocument` поможет. Так что, выбираете нужный контрол и привязываете его к свойству, которое содержит в себе текст.

Comment: Благодарю=)))))