# Прерывание выполняющийся задачи по нажатию кнопки. c#

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Есть задача:

"Написать приложение просмотра погоды с UI. Требований к симпатичности UI нет. При нажатии кнопки "Узнать погоду" она меняется на "Отмена" и в это время приложение запрашивает результат у любого внешнего сервиса погоды. Затем на основании результатов запрашивает случайную картинку о полученной погоде из любого поисковика и отображает краткие сведения о погоде и картинку в окне. Кнопка "Отмена" меняется обратно. Пока идёт запрос, можно нажать "Отмена" чтобы его прервать."

Собственно проблема с прерыванием запроса, при нажатии кнопки создаётся поток, в котором выполняются запросы, и затем происходит заполнение контролов данными, из этих запросов. Но почему-то при повторном нажатии кнопки, до выполнении всего запроса, поток не прерывается. Совсем уже не понимаю в чем может быть дело.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using WeatherForecastApp.WeatherInfo;



namespace WeatherForecastApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //Проверка статуса кнопки, пока кнопка не была нажата переменная хранит false
        private bool btnPush = false;
      
        private void btnMain_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                //Фоновый поток в котором будет выполняться запрос, и заполнение ui элементов данными
                Thread backThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(loadData));
                backThread.Name = "myThread";
                backThread.IsBackground = true;
                //Если false, значит запустить запрос
                if (!btnPush)
                {
                    btnPush = true;
                    btnMain.Content = "Cancel";
                    backThread.Start();
                     //loadData();
                }
                //Если true, прервать запрос
                else
                {
                    btnPush = false;
                    backThread.Abort();
                    backThread.Join();
                    MessageBox.Show("Прервано");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
           

        }

        //Метод выполняющий запрос
        private async void loadData()
        {
            
                  //url  api сайта с погодой
          string urlWeather = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Saint Petersburg&appid=8c5212cec55de3c0ae64db31343f805a&units=metric";
          
            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(urlWeather);
            WebResponse webResponse = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
            //Перменная для хранение результата запроса
            string response;
            //Читаем и сохраняем полученные данные
            using (StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                response = await strReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
            //Конвертируем данные в специально созданную сущность для удобство чтения
            WeatherResponse weatherResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherResponse>(response);
            //Переменная хранящая описание текущих погодных условий, для поиска нужной картинки
            string weatherName = weatherResponse.Weather[0].description;
            //searchImage(weatherName);

            //Url поисковика для передачи веб браузеру, в строку url передается название погоды, например overcast clouds
            string urlImage = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + weatherName + "&sxsrf=AOaemvLy4R0Xmx2A_aaD7zlWfr5cDOyWbA:1639733422777&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=2ahUKEwj5_MKBw-r0AhVupZUCHdaQAtMQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=2560&bih=1297&dpr=1";
          //  string urlImage = "https://www.shutterstock.com/search/" + weatherName;
            //Имитация продолжительног выполнения запроса для проверки функционала отмены запроса
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            //Вызов UI потока для заполняния UI элементов полученными данными
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { 
                //Ищем нужную картинку
                     myWebBrowser.Navigate(urlImage);
                lblWeatherName.Content = "Weather: " + weatherName;
                //Если в контроле ListBox сохранились прошлые данные, чистим коллекцию
                if (listTemp.Items != null)
                    listTemp.Items.Clear();
                listTemp.Items.Add($"{weatherResponse.Main.temp} C");
                listTemp.Items.Add($"Feels like: {weatherResponse.Main.feels_like} C");
                listTemp.Items.Add($"Humidity: {weatherResponse.Main.humidity}%");
                //Тоже самое с второй коллекцией
                if (listWind.Items != null)
                    listWind.Items.Clear();
                listWind.Items.Add($"Speed m/s: {weatherResponse.wind.speed}");
                listWind.Items.Add($"Direction: {weatherResponse.wind.deg}");
                //По завершеннии добавки данных меняем текст на кнопке
                btnMain.Content = "Find weather";
            });
            //Кнопка снова готова к старту запроса
             btnPush = false;
            
        }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Кажется вы сильно перестарались, например, чтобы показать картинку в WPF по ссылке, не нужен браузер, достаточно контрола Image. Далее, вы используете очень давно устаревший WebRequest, неужели вас вот прямо сейчас учат использовать это старьё? Учили ли вас использовать привязки Data Bindings? Если да, то почему не используете? Рассказывали ли про MVVM? Если вы используете async-await, тогда зачем вам Thread? Не могу уловить, где требования к заданию выполняются, а где ваше личное творчество, следовательно не могу понять, что можно исправлять, а что не стоит.

Comment: `Thread.Abort();` при использовании async-await это не сработает, потому что выполнение асинхронного кода при отсутствии контекста синхронизации распределяется по нескольким потокам, тругими словами, созданный вами поток завершается в том месте, где встречается первый await в методе, потому что выполнение кода уходит в другой поток. Следовательно и абортить нечего. Другими словами, вы используете конфликтующие друг с другом технологии, расскажите, какая из них вас интересует по заданию? Ну и Thread.Abort устарел давно, тоже. Какая версия дотнета используется?

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения. Это тестовое задание, и решить его можно как угодно, главное оптимально. WebRequest подсмотрел в ролике на ютубе, так как до этого вообще не писал подобных веб запросов. До MVVM осталось пару глав, изучаю язык по Троелсену. А с многопоточностью просто запутался. 
Думаю по заданию от меня ждут самого оптимального решения.
Использую .net FrameWork 4.7.2.

Comment: Можете ли вы использовать .NET 6? Есть ли каки-либо непреодолимые причины оставаться на устаревшем Framework? Например в новом дотнете есть встроенный JSON и подключение NuGet пакета Newtonsoft.Json не требуется. И кстати, WebBrowser, это Internet Explorer 11, и его уже даже в Microsoft отправили на пенсию. Если уж так сильно нужен браузер, можно использовать WebView2, то есть последний современный Microsoft Edge. Мне кажется, для тестового задания гораздо эффективнее использовать современные технологии. Я сейчас напишу ответ и перечислю там все советы к решению, но решать вам придется самому.

Comment: Есть, конечно. Просто в книге по которой я изучаю язык используется выше упомянутая версия. Я не уверен что примеры из книги будут работать на более новой версии. А насчет браузера, я не знаю как получить именно первую картинку из поисковика, по этому использовал браузер для отображения всех картинок из поисковика.

Comment: Благодарю вас за потраченное время!

Comment: Дотнет практически полностью обратно совместим со всеми своими предыдущими версиями, в частности среди вашего кода я не нахожу моментов, где оно могло бы быть несовместимо. Попробуйте перенести код в новый проект, убедитесь сами. Ответ уже пишу.

Comment: Проверил, так и есть!
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отмена операции - это последнее, о чем здесь следует переживать, напишу об этом в самом низу. Первое, что нужно сделать, это бросить устаревшие технологии. Второе - разобраться с многопоточностью.

По порядку:

#### WebRequest устарел

Об этом написано в [его документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=net-6.0#remarks). Используйте `HttpClient`.

Особенность `HttpClient` в том, что его экземпляр не нужно создавать на каждый запрос. И самый простой вариант - использовать статическое поле.

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
```

А сам запрос выполнить еще легче, чем с `WebRequest`. Мы же на .NET 6, давайте использовать его на полную катушку.

Но для начала создадим модель данных. Берем Json из запроса погоды по ссылке, которую вы показали, выполняем в браузере, далее открываем Visual Studio, Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as classes. Осталось переименовать RootObject и получится вот так.

```cs
public class WeatherResponse
{
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public Weather[] weather { get; set; }
    public string _base { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public int visibility { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Snow snow { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public int timezone { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int cod { get; set; }
}

public class Coord
{
    public float lon { get; set; }
    public float lat { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public float temp { get; set; }
    public float feels_like { get; set; }
    public float temp_min { get; set; }
    public float temp_max { get; set; }
    public int pressure { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    public int speed { get; set; }
    public int deg { get; set; }
}

public class Snow
{
    public float _1h { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
    public int all { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    public int type { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int sunrise { get; set; }
    public int sunset { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}
```

3,5 клика мышкой. Если здесь модель выглядит богаче, чем нужно, можно просто поудалять лишнее.

Ну и сам запрос

```cs
string url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Saint%20Petersburg&appid=8c5212cec55de3c0ae64db31343f805a&units=metric";
WeatherResponse weather = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherResponse>(url);
```

Согласитесь, так проще. В .NET Framework 4.x нет метода `GetFromJsonAsync`.

#### Асинхронность и многопоточность

Никогда не путайте эти 2 понятия, это 2 большие разницы. Углубляться не буду, можете почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1250881/373567) и [в документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

В документации обратите внимание на разницу между CPU-интенсивными операциями

```cs
await Task.Run(() => СуперТяжелыеВычисления());
```

и I/O-зависимыми операциями.

```cs
await АсинхронныйЗапросВСеть();
```

Запрос в сеть или в базу или к диску, не требует явного запуска потока. Асинхронная операция вообще может не требовать выделенных потоков для работы.

#### WPF привязка данных

Чтобы реализовать привязку данных, надо сделать 3 вещи:

Иметь класс с публичным свойством

```cs
public class MainViewModel // Привет, MVVM!
{
    public string КакоеТоСвойство { get; set; }
}
```

Назначить `DataContext`. Это можно сделать разными способами, самый простой вот:

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

И просто привязаться к нему в XAML

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding КакоеТоСвойство}"/>
```

Правда, чтобы привязки работали в реальном времени, а не только из конструктора вьюмодели, придется реализовать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged` для вьюмодели, но это уже другая история, окунуться в нее можно например [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1363206/373567), здесь на StackOverflow просто сотни примеров MVVM для WPF. Это важно, потому что вменяемые приложения под WPF без MVVM не пишутся. Сделайте паузу и разберитесь с этим. В код-бихайнде, то есть в классе `MainWindow` должно стать пусто, не должно быть кода кроме того что я выше показал.

#### Браузер

Не секрет, что гугл ненавидит ботов, и просто стукнуться туда с помощью `HttpClient` не получится. Пусть будет браузер, ваша идея вполне себе имеет право на жизнь, но с осторожностью. Браузер - штука тяжелая.

Есть непростой, но вполне вменяемый контрол `WebView2`, он не имеет ничего общего с устаревшим `WebBrowser`. Я не буду нагружать вас примерами, начните с чтения [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf). Предупрежу только, что придется написать несколько очень маленьких javascript скриптов, чтобы распарсить ответ гугла и забрать из него картинку. HTML можно парсить и в C#, для этого рекомендую одну из 2 библиотек, на выбор: HtmlAgilityPack и AngleSharp.

Картинка для WPF - это просто ссылка, `string`. Берете свойство типа `string`, прямо как я выше показал, берете `<Image Source="{Binding ТоСамоеСвойство}"/>`, и готово, WPF сам вам загрузит эту картинку из сети в интерфейс. То есть самого `WebView2` может и не быть в интерфейсе вовсе, всё для чего вам нужен браузер - это добыть нужную ссылку на картинку.

#### Отмена асинхронной операции

Эта тема весьма простая, все что нужно знать - это то что существует класс `CancellationToken` и то что практически все асинхронные методы в дотнете его принимают в качестве аргумента. Пример есть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257322/373567).

---

Пока достаточно. Хотя нет, самый главный совет - никогда не используйте `async void` и обязательно разберитесь, почему.

Comment: Спасибо, приму все вами сказанное к сведению!

Comment: @DrainRanger92 дописал про отмену, чуть не забыл :)