# C# резиновая вёрстка

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: Скриншот приложения Windows Form]

Делаю на C# Windows Form приложение, вот не могу разобраться с резиновой вёрсткой, всё пока что так туго. 2 дня пытаюсь наладить.
Сидебар (там тоже есть panel) слева имеет такие св-ва:

```
Anchor: Top, Left
Dock: None
```

Он не закреплён в родительском контейнере.

Сверху  statusStrip:

```
Anchor: Top, Left
Dock: Top
```

Дальше у нас остаётся форма почты.
под этой формой есть panel (тоже не закреплён в род контейнер):

```
Anchor: Top, Left
Dock: None
```

В другом классе то есть форме, это как отдельный компонент, при нажатии на сидебар открывается нужная страница. (работает если сидебар не закреплён, иначе не работает).

В чём проблема? Ролик на ютубе смотрел, не помогло вообще.
Desinger.cs:

```
namespace CopterV8
{
    partial class App
    {
    
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Код, автоматически созданный конструктором форм Windows

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip statusStrip;
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(App));
            this.Close = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
            this.Networks = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownButton();
            this.sidebar = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.Menu = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.menuButton = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.Home = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.panel3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.Settings = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.panel4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.Help = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.panel5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.About = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.panel6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.Software = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.sidebarTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.NotifyIconHi = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(this.components);
            this.Container = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            statusStrip = new System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip();
            statusStrip.SuspendLayout();
            this.sidebar.SuspendLayout();
            this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.menuButton)).BeginInit();
            this.panel2.SuspendLayout();
            this.panel3.SuspendLayout();
            this.panel4.SuspendLayout();
            this.panel5.SuspendLayout();
            this.panel6.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // statusStrip
            // 
            statusStrip.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(35)))), ((int)(((byte)(40)))), ((int)(((byte)(45)))));
            statusStrip.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.None;
            statusStrip.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
            statusStrip.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 10.8F);
            statusStrip.GripStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripGripStyle.Visible;
            statusStrip.ImageScalingSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
            statusStrip.ImeMode = System.Windows.Forms.ImeMode.On;
            statusStrip.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.Close,
            this.Networks});
            statusStrip.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            statusStrip.Name = "statusStrip";
            statusStrip.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;
            statusStrip.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 31);
            statusStrip.SizingGrip = false;
            statusStrip.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // Close
            // 
            this.Close.ActiveLinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.Close.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemAlignment.Right;
            this.Close.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("Close.BackgroundImage")));
            this.Close.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;
            this.Close.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
            this.Close.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.Close.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("Close.Image")));
            this.Close.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.Close.LinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.Close.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(20, 3, 0, 3);
            this.Close.Name = "Close";
            this.Close.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
            this.Close.RightToLeftAutoMirrorImage = true;
            this.Close.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 25);
            this.Close.Text = "Close";
            this.Close.VisitedLinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.Close.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Close_Click);
            // 
            // Networks
            // 
            this.Networks.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.Networks.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("Networks.Image")));
            this.Networks.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.Networks.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(40, 2, 0, 0);
            this.Networks.Name = "Networks";
            this.Networks.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            this.Networks.ShowDropDownArrow = false;
            this.Networks.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 29);
            this.Networks.Text = "Networks";
            this.Networks.ToolTipText = "Networks";
            this.Networks.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Networks_Click);
            // 
            // sidebar
            // 
            this.sidebar.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(35)))), ((int)(((byte)(40)))), ((int)(((byte)(45)))));
            this.sidebar.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.sidebar.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
            this.sidebar.Controls.Add(this.panel3);
            this.sidebar.Controls.Add(this.panel4);
            this.sidebar.Controls.Add(this.panel5);
            this.sidebar.Controls.Add(this.panel6);
            this.sidebar.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.sidebar.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 450);
            this.sidebar.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 450);
            this.sidebar.Name = "sidebar";
            this.sidebar.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 450);
            this.sidebar.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.Menu);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.menuButton);
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.panel1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 79);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // Menu
            // 
            this.Menu.AutoSize = true;
            this.Menu.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 10.8F);
            this.Menu.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.Menu.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(104, 29);
            this.Menu.Name = "Menu";
            this.Menu.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(57, 25);
            this.Menu.TabIndex = 1;
            this.Menu.Text = "Menu";
            // 
            // menuButton
            // 
            this.menuButton.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
            this.menuButton.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("menuButton.Image")));
            this.menuButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(29, 29);
            this.menuButton.Name = "menuButton";
            this.menuButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(32, 37);
            this.menuButton.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.menuButton.TabIndex = 0;
            this.menuButton.TabStop = false;
            this.menuButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuButton_Click);
            // 
            // panel2
            // 
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.Home);
            this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 82);
            this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
            this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 40);
            this.panel2.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // Home
            // 
            this.Home.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.Home.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 10.8F);
            this.Home.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.Home.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("Home.Image")));
            this.Home.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.Home.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-12, -10);
            this.Home.Name = "Home";
            this.Home.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(30, 0, 0, 0);
            this.Home.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(229, 62);
            this.Home.TabIndex = 2;
            this.Home.Text = "    Home";
            this.Home.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // panel3
            // 
            this.panel3.Controls.Add(this.Settings);
            this.panel3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 128);
            this.panel3.Name = "panel3";
            this.panel3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 40);
            this.panel3.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // Settings
            // 
            this.Settings.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.Settings.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 10.8F);
            this.Settings.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.Settings.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("Settings.Image")));
            this.Settings.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.Settings.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-12, -10);
            this.Settings.Name = "Settings";
            this.Settings.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(30, 0, 0, 0);
            this.Settings.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(229, 62);
            this.Settings.TabIndex = 2;
            this.Settings.Text = "    Settings";
            this.Settings.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // panel4
            // 
            this.panel4.Controls.Add(this.Help);
            this.panel4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 174);
            this.panel4.Name = "panel4";
            this.panel4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 40);
            this.panel4.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // Help
            // 
            this.Help.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.Help.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 10.8F);
            this.Help.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.Help.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("Help.Image")));
            this.Help.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.Help.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-12, -10);
            this.Help.Name = "Help";
            this.Help.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(30, 0, 0, 0);
            this.Help.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(229, 62);
            this.Help.TabIndex = 2;
            this.Help.Text = "    Help";
            this.Help.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.Help.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Help_Click);
            // 
            // panel5
            // 
            this.panel5.Controls.Add(this.About);
            this.panel5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 220);
            this.panel5.Name = "panel5";
            this.panel5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 40);
            this.panel5.TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // About
            // 
            this.About.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.About.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 10.8F);
            this.About.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.About.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("About.Image")));
            this.About.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.About.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-12, -10);
            this.About.Name = "About";
            this.About.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(30, 0, 0, 0);
            this.About.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(229, 62);
            this.About.TabIndex = 2;
            this.About.Text = "    About";
            this.About.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // panel6
            // 
            this.panel6.Controls.Add(this.Software);
            this.panel6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 266);
            this.panel6.Name = "panel6";
            this.panel6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 40);
            this.panel6.TabIndex = 5;
            // 
            // Software
            // 
            this.Software.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.Software.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 10.8F);
            this.Software.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.Software.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("Software.Image")));
            this.Software.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.Software.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-12, -10);
            this.Software.Name = "Software";
            this.Software.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(30, 0, 0, 0);
            this.Software.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(229, 62);
            this.Software.TabIndex = 2;
            this.Software.Text = "    Software";
            this.Software.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.Software.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Software_Click);
            // 
            // sidebarTimer
            // 
            this.sidebarTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.sidebarTimer_Tick);
            // 
            // NotifyIconHi
            // 
            this.NotifyIconHi.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("NotifyIconHi.Icon")));
            this.NotifyIconHi.Text = "NotifyIconHi";
            this.NotifyIconHi.Visible = true;
            // 
            // Container
            // 
            this.Container.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 31);
            this.Container.Name = "Container";
            this.Container.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(600, 419);
            this.Container.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // App
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))));
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.Container);
            this.Controls.Add(statusStrip);
            this.Controls.Add(this.sidebar);
            this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
            this.Name = "App";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "Copter V8/Rocket";
            this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.App_Shown);
            statusStrip.ResumeLayout(false);
            statusStrip.PerformLayout();
            this.sidebar.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel1.PerformLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.menuButton)).EndInit();
            this.panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel3.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel4.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel5.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel6.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button Home;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label Menu;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox menuButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button Settings;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button Help;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel5;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button About;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer sidebarTimer;
        private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon NotifyIconHi;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel Close;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownButton Networks;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel Container;
        private System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel sidebar;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel6;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button Software;
    }
}
```

**P.S(я не хочу писать на WPF)**

Comment: И как по скриншоту понять, что у вас там не так? Гадание по фотографии? :) Нужно видеть код .designer.cs формы. И здесь в одном посте 2 вопроса, по правилам StackOverflow: 1 пост - 1 вопрос. В противном случае ответ вы скорее всего не получите, а вопрос будет закрыт. И про WPF это вы зря. Я по идее знаю как сделать и там и там, но в WPF это сделать в разы проще. Если кратко, вас спасёт не `Dock`, а `TableLayoutPanel` вместо него. Плюс с `FlowLayoutPanel` познакомтесь.

Comment: Почему зря про WPF ? Если знаете, то можете конечно мне код выслать если хотите. про вопросы учту. @aepot

Comment: Да без разницы, чего я хочу, важнее чего хотите вы. Отредактируйте пост так, чтобы в нем остался один вопрос, а не два. А пока непонятно, на что отвечать.

Comment: @aepot - отредактировал, добавил код как ты просил.

Comment: Если хотите начать WPF, то начните с XAML,  привязок данных `Binding` (в формах они тоже кстати [есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567) и работают точно так же), и обязательно начать писать именно по правилам шаблона проектирования MVVM. Если все сделаете правильно, наступит счастье, а винформы покажутся ночным кошмаром. Ну хотя-бы [вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567) или [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1363206/373567).

Comment: Вот, теперь хорошо оформили. Прямо сейчас с телефона, написать решение не смогу, может позднее, или кто-то другой поможет. А вы пока подумайте, а стоит ли оно того вообще.

Comment: @aepot - посмотрел WPF, чёт почему то понравилось, думаю всё перенести на WPF.

Comment: Поразбирайтесь обязательно с MVVM шаблоном и привязками данных, это важно. Без них WPF не крут. Если этот вопрос не актуален, вы можете его удалить.

Comment: @aepot - хорошо, узнаю что такое MVVM, в ютубе смотрю крутые дизайны на WPF очень впечатляет 

Comment: Долеко ходить не надо, я вам 2 ссылки кинул, что посмотреть. Во второй там еще 2 ссылки на примеры.