# (WPF) Массив кнопок по количеству папок в таблицу

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

## Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста понять как сделать следующее (Только знакомлюсь с WPF):

Есть N-ое количество папок, в которых расположены некоторые файлы. Один из них это картинка.

Нужно вывести через цикл кнопки в количестве равному количеству папок(лучше всего в grid по 5 в строке) и соответственно необходим скролл, для того что бы можно было листать если количество кнопок не влезает в окно целиком. Всё это нужно засунуть в grid с двумя столбцами. левый для кнопок, а правый для картинки(при наведении на любую из кнопок должна появиться картинка из соответствующей папки)

**Допустим как зациклено создать кнопки, я разобрался**

---

***C#***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Navigation;

namespace Conceptor5._0
{
public partial class VU : Window
{
   public static string Tematic = "";
    public VU()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Button[] btns = new Button[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < btns.Length; i++)
        {
            var btn = new Button
            {
                Content = "Button-" + i.ToString(),
                 

            };
            btnsPanel.Children.Add(btn);
            btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn_Click);
           
        }

    }
    void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Button buttonThatWasClicked = (Button)sender;
        MessageBox.Show("Button pressed " + buttonThatWasClicked.Content);

    }
    private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow win2 = new MainWindow();
        win2.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    
}

}
```

***Xalm***

```
<Window x:Class="Conceptor5._0.VU"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Conceptor5._0"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
     Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
WindowState="Maximized"
WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="interface\background\Background.jpg"/>
</Window.Background>
<StackPanel>
    <Image Height="100" Width="267" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown"
        Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/button_nazad (1).png"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/button_nazad.png"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid Height="100">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="267*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="133*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Name="btnsPanel">

            </StackPanel>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Height="100" Width="267" Source="/Resources/test.jpg" >

            </Image>

        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
       
    


</StackPanel>
```

**Но даже так, при запуске картинка не появляется**

---

[image: запущенное]

При этом в редакторе картинка имеется

---

[image: Редактор]

**Вот такой результат я хочу получить**

---

[image: Желаемое]

**Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться с данным вопросом. И если будет возможность на примере. Заранее спасибо**

Comment: Неправильно вы знакомитесь с WPF, [вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1363206/373567) надо. По другим механикам здесь тоже информации полно, надо только поискать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свой вопрос я решил полностью. Спасибо за ссылку  товарищу с ником aepot.

Ниже привожу решение которое мне подошло (естественно нулевик, чтоб если потребуется другим, было проще разобраться)

Xalm

```
<Window x:Class="Testmassiv.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Testmassiv"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
     d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindow}">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Width:" Margin="5" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBox Width="100" Margin="5" MaxLength="2" Text="{Binding Width, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Height:" Margin="5" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBox Width="100" Margin="5" MaxLength="2" Text="{Binding Height, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Row="1" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="4" BorderBrush="#add8e6" Margin="3">
                    <Button x:Name="bq" Content="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="20" Click="Button_Click" MouseLeftButtonDown="bq_MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <Button.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Background.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
                        </Button.Background>
                    </Button>
                    
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Height}" Columns="{Binding Width}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Testmassiv
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (Content.ToString() != null)
        {
            var senderBtn = sender as Button;
            MessageBox.Show(senderBtn.Content.ToString());
        }
        
    }

   
}
}
```

Class View model

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private int width;
private int height;

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new         PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public int Width
{
    get => width;
    set
    {
        width = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Width));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
    }
}

public int Height
{
    get => height;
    set
    {
        height = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Height));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
    }
}

public IEnumerable<string> Items => Directory.EnumerateDirectories("C:\\Users\\verma\\source\\repos\\ForConcept").Select(System.IO.Path.GetFileName);



}
```

На дизайн прошу не реагировать, все ради теста
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Что касаемо вопроса, вывода отдельной картинки то Grid в Grid.
Еще раз спасибо aepot-у и надеюсь тема кому-то поможет