# Как сделать, чтобы приложение масштабировалось пропорционально?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml

Подскажите, необходимо, чтобы при уменьшении приложения по вертикали, оно также равномерно уменьшалось и по горизонтали, и также в обратном порядке, как такое можно реализовать?
В голову пришла только идея через событие sizeChanged, но оно работает крайне криво.

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Width != IsChangedWindow.wigth)
            {
                Height = Width / 16 * 9;
                IsChangedWindow.wigth = Width;
                IsChangedWindow.height = Height;
            }
            else if (Height != IsChangedWindow.height)
            {
                Width = Height / 9 * 16;
                IsChangedWindow.wigth = Width;
                IsChangedWindow.height = Height;
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1295679/220553

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы когда я изменял ширину моего окна, так же пропорционально ему изменялась высота и наоборот

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15959611/6808809